# How to get website filename without extension and ?id=someid using php

Tags: php

I would like to get a website filename after domain without the extension and any query string.

I try to resolve with basename, but if the user put ? after .php the output is display incorrect.

https://example.com/customers/NameIWant.php
returns: NameIWan

https://example.com/customers/NameIWant.php?someting
returns: NameIWan.php?someting

```php
$url= basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '.php' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])
```

This $url I will use it to query MySQL.

And I don't need query in URL or any code only the name of the current file.

Comment: @kerbholz Deleted, I'm new on the platform, I do not know exactly how tags work. I deleted the tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `parse_url()` and `basename()` to get the filename only:

```
<?php

$url = 'https://example.com/customers/NameIWant.php?someting';

// /customers/NameIWant.php
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);

// NameIWant
$filename = basename($path, '.php');
```

(Replace `$url = 'https://example.com/customers/NameIWant.php?someting';` with `$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`)

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php